# How to create a table with a field 99% INT; 1% STR values?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, schema

I am creating a table in PostgreSQL and looking for a best approach that I should follow.

One of my fields are mostly consists of integer values. But really mostly.

Like: `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20 and over`

Last one, ***20 and over***, kills everything. If it wouldn't be there I am going to create that table with integer field.

Should I create the field in `VARCHAR(11)` type, just because of the 1% string field? Or is there any other method to solve this issue smoothly?

Comment: Is the list of possible values really that narrow or was that for example purposes?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently you want to store some kind of range where most of the ranges just contain a single element and one of them is open ended.

You did not explain *how* you want to use those values.

If you **only** use them for display purposes and never, ever under no circumstance (ever!) have to do any calculations on them, a `text` column might be enough.

However, I have never encountered a situation where numbers weren't intended to be treated as numbers in the long run.

Depending on how you use the values, I can think of two solutions: either use a [range type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html) where most ranges only contain a single element. Whether or not that makes sense depends on the way you use that value. Maybe the 20 single values actually mean a range from 1 to 20 - it's hard to tell from your question

Or use a two columns: one integer and one indicating the "*and above*". If you only have the choice between "exactly that value" and "that value and above", I would probably use a `boolean` column that indicates that the value is the lower end of a range.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly advise you to use the most appropriate data type possible - if the data is integers, then use an integer type!

You want PostgreSQL's [`generate_series`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-srf.html)

This code will generate as many random integers between 0 and 20 as you want.

```
SELECT (20 * random())::INTEGER AS rand FROM generate_series(1, 10);
```

Result -

```
rand
0
15
2
10
14
14
10
0
18
18
```

See the fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=264a60712e923e5de4ffdbc0cf782df6)! You can vary the second parameter to whatever value suits you!

To generate random text, you can use this code:

```
SELECT MD5(random()::TEXT) FROM GENERATE_SERIES(1, 5);
```

Result:

```
md5
de5161e6ed7492d046d02bfc5c166c86
a8818e4e472c4a8a923abf2c9e97a70c
398300e6a10e4c493b64403adeeac3c7
bf548d3db7763e11ee05e41ab0f2b3d9
c914d60c26a5c75fa794ef119ed70c10
```

To generate text only, you can use the [`REPLACE`](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-replace/) and/or the [`TRANSLATE`](https://w3resource.com/PostgreSQL/translate-function.php) functions to change the MD5 numeric data to the empty string. Lots of good "tricks" to be found [here](https://www.dbrnd.com/2016/04/postgresql-how-to-generate-a-random-token-string/), [here](https://dataschool.com/learn-sql/random-sequences/) and [here](https://regilero.github.io/postgresql/english/2017/06/26/postgresql_advanced_generate_series/).

The best though would be the [`REGEXP_REPLACE`](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/regexp_replace/) function. You could do something like this:

```
WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT MD5(random()::TEXT) AS rand FROM GENERATE_SERIES(1, 5)
)
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(rand,'[[:digit:]]','','g') AS letters FROM cte
```

Result:

```
letters
addebafaeb
ccdfaddbdccadc
debdbdfabefbeff
debdaecabef
ebfbaeefdbc
```

p.s. welcome to the forum!